# Rewrite rule for dynamic subdomain redirecting each file with subdomain arguments

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect all the calls to files in a subdomain with an extra variable. like if a user access `www.domain.com/news.php` and in the subdomain he accesses the same page then it should add an extra argument to the url like `xyz.domain.com/news.php` should be re written like it calls the file `news.php?subdomain=xyz`. Also i have other rules for just simple domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?subdomain=%1 [L]
```

Comment: you meant if user had accessed the www.domain.com/news.php and after that xyz.domain.com/news.php it should be rewritten but if he did not browsed the first one , don't rewrite?

Comment: No. All the files that are accessed through a subdomain  xxx.domain.com/file.php should be re written to domain.com/file.php?var=xxx ?  Similarly for file2.php like xxx.domain.com/file2.php should be domain.com/file2.php?var=xxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 [R=301,NC,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI}?subdomain=%1 [L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   http://www.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}&subdomain=%1 [L]
```

Comment: I do not need a permanent redirection. the url in the browser will be like xyz.domain.com/file.php  But in actual the HTACCESS file has to call the file like  domain.com/file.php?subdomain=xyz

Comment: I mean when the call to a file is from the main site like www.domain.com/file.php then it should be straight as it is but for the subdomain calls like xyz.domain.com/file.php  the rewrite for this should be like domain.com/file.php?subdomain=xyz similar for all subdomain file calls. acutally i want for each subdomain file calls to have a get variable subdomain set for that with the value. And for all the calls the  browser address will be the same as written by the user not physical redirects.

Comment: @HardCode when host is **xyz.domain.com** changing it to  **domain.com** requires external redirect

Comment: the address will not change i am writing the rewrite rule that how will the rewrite rule deal with the call that is in browser. if the user accesses xyz.domain.com/file.php  then actually what the htaccess will do is to take this call and point it like domain.com/file.php?subdomain=xyz. this should be the rewrite rule but the address in the browser should be xyz.domain.com/file.php

Comment: Will that work for the index file also. like xyz.domain.com will go to the index file with the subdomain arguments???

Comment: will these subdomains allow the "-" character or not?

Comment: **(.*)** in rewrite condition means anything except new line character! so yes!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4012/discussion-between-hardcode-and-death)

Answer (score 0):

The solution pointed to by adaptr at: https://serverfault.com/a/409171/128746 - would solve this problem very well.